# How do I determine whether a cell is merged in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
 var lstrow= sheet.getLastRow();

 for (var i = 0; i < mergerange.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(mergerange[i].getA1Notation());
        Logger.log(mergerange[i].getDisplayValue());
        mergerange[i].breakApart();
 }

var mergerange = sheet.getRange(19,9,lstrow).getMergedRanges();
```

The above code unmerges merged cells.

I want to run the code that unmerges only when the cell is merged.

Is there a way to check whether cells are merged in gogle.spreadsheet?

Comment: It's wise to never merge cells in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Range.isPartOfMerge()`

Here's the example code from the documentation.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");

// True if any of the cells in A1:B3 is included in a merge.
var isPartOfMerge = range.isPartOfMerge();
```

- [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isPartOfMerge())

You can also identify merged ranges with `Range.getMergedRanges()`

Here's the example code from that section

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");

var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation());
  Logger.log(mergedRanges[i].getDisplayValue());
}
```

- [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges)